# How to change hint text color of edittext when TextInputLayout is used

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have a screen with edittexts. When these edittexts are disabled, I need the hint color to be in one color
 [image]

When these are enabled, I need the hint to be in a different color like this

[image]

This works fine when I tried like this

```
     editText.setHintTextColor(color);
```

The problem is , I have to use a `TextInputlayout` to show the floating hint. So, When I add the `EditText` inside `TextInputLayout` this code doesn't work at all. I tried many things with `TextInputLayout` as shown [here](https://www.journaldev.com/14748/android-textinputlayout-example). But nothing works. All I need is the hint text color (Not floating hint text) of the EditText should be in one color when enabled , and in different color when disabled, when used inside a  `TextInputLayout`. Please help!

Note: My question is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738544/how-to-change-the-floating-hint-color-of-textinputlayout-if-edittext-inside-is-d).  There , it is mentioned about the **floating hint text of the TextInputLayout when it is focused**  What I am talking about the normal hint text when the edit text is not focused and also when it is empty.

Comment: @0X0nosugar My question is different. I'm asking about the `EditText` hint. not the floating hint of `TextInputLayout`. This answer I have already seen and tried. It changes floating hint color(When focused). But not EditText Hint color (When focus is not there)

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your App theme

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/color</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/color</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/color</item>
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/color</item>
```