# How to not change the color of the label while setting error to particular textinputlayout having edittext inside it?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am using a Textinputlayout and edittext inside it, problem is when I set the error to the textinputlayout at the time of validations , it changes the color of my hint label also to red. I want to put another color instead of that red color when error comes.Only the underline color and error text should turn to red.

[image]

above shown in the pic is the problem, I dont want the email label with red color.

Below is my code.

## xml file

```
     <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
 app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/et1"
            android:padding="0dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:textColorHint="#3F4B5B"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


#java file


#Declarations
 private TextInputLayout emailerror;
 private EditText Email;

#On create 
    Email=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
     emailerror=(TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.et1);

#Inside validation method
 emailerror.setError("Enter a valid email");
```

## Style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
         TextInputLayout text color
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#e0e0e0</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#52AF44</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#3F4B5B</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>


<!--    <style name="error" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item> &lt;!&ndash;apply the color you wat here &ndash;&gt;
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#3E4A58</item>
       &lt;!&ndash; <item name="android:textColorHint">#3a52a6</item>&ndash;&gt;
       &lt;!&ndash; <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>&ndash;&gt;
    </style>-->

    <!--<style name="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/TextLabel1</item>
        <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/error_appearance</item>
        <item name="counterTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Counter</item>
        <item name="counterOverflowTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Design.Counter.Overflow</item>
    </style>-->

    <style name="error_appearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextLabel1" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarColoredBackArrow" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="EditTextHint" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!--<item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>-->
        <item name="android:textColorHint">#989898</item>
     <!--   <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your color</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>-->
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.App.Spinner" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
        <item name="overlapAnchor">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: I solve it by setting the backgroundTintList (the underline, officially called Activation indicator) to red and make a TextView holding the error message. Which means I totally give up using the input Layout.error method

Answer (score 0):

You need to override text input layout default style, with your customstyle.

styles.xml

```
<resources>

 <style name="TextLabel">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorPrimary</item> <!-- Your Hint Color -->
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="error_appearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

activity_layout.xml

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_appearance">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edt_mobile"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_phone_iphone_black_24dp"
                android:drawablePadding="8dp"
                android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:hint="@string/email"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textColor="#000" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

---

Focused:

[image: Focused]

Without focus:

[image: Without focus]

Error message:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I need to keep the hint label colour as it is for focused, not focused and at the time of error. I should never change no matter what the state is focused or not focused.

Comment: @YeshaShah So don't apply your custom hint label style, then it will take default style for textinput layout.

Comment: @YeshaShah check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738544/how-to-change-the-floating-hint-color-of-textinputlayout-if-edittext-inside-is-d

Comment: @AnilGhodake still both the colors are chaging. I used your code but there is no effect.

Comment: @YeshaShah, I just edited my answer. Added **error appearance** and **TextLabel1** style. Try these two styles now. Also applied these styles to textinput layout and **removed theme** applied to text input layout.

Comment: Still it is taking color of error only for errortext and labeltext both.

Comment: @YeshaShah, Can you update your question with latest implementation(including Style)? Because in my case its working properly.

Comment: I have updated my answer with style.xml @AnilGhodake

Comment: @YeshaShah, I have updated my answer now. removed hint style and added one more style and applied it as **android:theme**. This solution should be worked now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183813/discussion-between-anil-ghodake-and-yesha-shah).

Comment: This is not working. I also followed the above suggestions with comments too.
I have spent almost 3 days for this still no luck.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this? kind of amazing that 3 years later this still an issue.

Comment: I solve it by setting the backgroundTintList (the underline, officially called Activation indicator) to red and make a TextView holding the error message. Which means I totally give up using the input Layout.error method