# Android: TextInputLayout - customize colors for hint, bottom line and error message

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-design-library, android-textinputlayout

My layout looks something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="E-mail"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I validate the user input, in case of invalid input, I add an error message like:

```
email_container.setError("You must fill this field!");
```

And the result is:

[image]

As you can see, and as it is expected actually, the **hint**, the **bottom line** and the **error message** are all in red.

**My goal**

To have a *separated* color for the *hint*. That is... keeping red the *bottom line* and the *message*, but use another color for the *hint* when in **error state**.

---

Already tried:

[How to change the floating hint color of TextInputLayout if EditText inside is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35738544)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53348723

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765159

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33709380

...and other solutions that try to solve the case when the `android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout` wrappers a simple `EditText`.

But, in my case I'm using `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout` and `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText`.

I have also tried to call `setErrorTextColor` and `setDefaultHintTextColor` after setting the error:

```
email_container.setError("You must fill this field!");
email_container.setErrorTextColor(new ColorStateList(states, colors));
email_container.setDefaultHintTextColor(new ColorStateList(statesHint, colorsHint));

// Also tried with other states, but nothing
int[][] states = new int[][] {
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled},
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled},
};

int[][] statesHint = new int[][] {
        new int[] { android.R.attr.state_enabled},
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_enabled},
};


int[] colors = new int[] {
        R.color.yellow,
        R.color.green,
};


int[] colorsHint = new int[] {
        R.color.black90,
        R.color.bt_text_blue,
};
```

But the only thing that I got, combining different states, was to make the **message** color different, but the **hint** and the **bottom line**, still had the same color.

Does anyone know how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

We can you custom style To customize TextInputLayout color . try this code to change TextInputLayout color code according to your need

**style.xml**

```
<style name="TextInputCustonColor" 
  parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    <!-- The color of the label  -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorPrimaryGolden</item>
    <!-- The color of the label -->
    <item name="android:colorError" tools:targetApi="o">@color/colorError</item>
    <!--the color of text-->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryGolden</item>
    <!--the color of background-->
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>
```

**activity.xml**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:errorEnabled="true"
    style="@style/TextInputCustonColor">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        style="@style/TextInputCustonColor"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:maxLines="1" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```